# AngularJS $parse/scope.$eval expression

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `$parse` to get my required result.

Here is my [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/77In0eoQCa23HssoKTNZ). Check `script.js` file

I want to parse an expression but I am getting error. How can I solve this kind of data?

Here is my code

```
    scope.data = {name:{_en:"username", _ar:'مفقود '}}

    // set variable in scope like scope.name_en = scope.data._en, scope.name_ar = scope.data._ar

    for(var i in scope.data) for(var j in scope.data[i]) scope[i+j] = scope.data[i][j];
    scope.messages2 = [{code:200, msg_en:"{{name_en}} is missing.", msg_ar:"مفقود {{name_ar}}"}];
    scope.finalMegs = [];

    for( var i in scope.messages2) {
      var obj = {};

      for(var j in scope.messages2[i]){
        if(j == 'code') continue;
        console.log(scope.$eval(scope.messages2[i][j]) );
        obj[j] = $parse(scope.messages2[i][j])
      }
      /*
      required object is {msg_en = "username is missing.", msg_ar:"مفقود مفقود "}
      */
      scope.finalMegs.push(obj);
    }
    console.log(scope.finalMegs);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of your messages is incorrect, so the messages can't be parsed by `$parse` or `$eval`. You should write them in this format:

```
scope.messages2 = [
   {
      code:200, 
      msg_en:"name_en + ' is missing.'", 
      msg_ar:"'مفقود ' + name_ar"
   }
];
```

Then if you want to get object with already formatted messages you should call `$parse` function in this way:

```
obj[j] = $parse(scope.messages2[i][j])(scope);
```

Because `$parse` converts angular expression to function, which you should call with your `scope` to get expected results.

But in your case, I think that you can replace those line to this also:

```
obj[j] = scope.$eval(scope.messages2[i][j]);
```

Result will be the same.

[Example on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/WbdI6TzEg3XsSfz1JvNC) (I've reformatted your example a little bit)

---

Please, take a look also at the example of usage scope.$eval [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) and [documentation about $parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).

Comment: Is there any way to execute that message ? Because then i have to update a lot of messages. Thank you

Comment: I don't think so. Imagine, that your original message already wrapped in double curly brackets and it looks like this: `"{{{{name_en}} is missing.}}"` when you pass it to `$eval` function or `$parse` service. It's just incorrect syntax. You can easily test it by adding this line to your html and you'll see, that it produces the same errors. If you have any questions, let me know!